# Не работает 'theme'=>'site' в main.php Yii

Tags: php, yii

Не работает

```
'theme'=>'site',
```

в main.php Yii
на сайте отображается только представление, без темы
вот структура

[image]

Comment: а какой лэйаут используется?

Comment: я их все удалил

Answer (score 0, accepted):

вроде как если лэйаутов нету, то он берет тему из main.php